# How to estimate GPU memory size and training time for fine tuning a LLM?

Tags: llm, fine-tuning, gpu

Here is what I observed for fine tuning [Flan-T5-base](https://huggingface.co/google/flan-t5-base):

GPU: 1 Nvidia V100 with 16 GB memory.
Flan-T5-base model size: 990 MB.
Script: [deep-learning-pytorch-huggingface](https://github.com/philschmid/deep-learning-pytorch-huggingface/blob/main/training/flan-t5-samsum-summarization.ipynb).
Samsum train dataset size: 370 MB.
Batch size: 8.
==> This will use 16 GB GPU memory(obtained from nvidia-smi command) and take about 1.5 hr to finish training.

Chnage to batch_size = 1.
==> This will use 7 GB GPU memory and take about 7.5 hr to finish training.

I would like to know if there is a rule of thumb which can be used to estimate GPU memory size and training time for fine tuning a LLM given GPU type and model, train data and batch sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article regarding this.
According to it:
"The equation ties together the throughput , the training time T, the model size N and the number of training tokens T:
T = 6ND     "

However, this is more of an estimate assuming peak throughput and other factors, so you should probably refer to the article for some context.

Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@dzmitrybahdanau/the-flops-calculus-of-language-model-training-3b19c1f025e4).

Edit: Formatting